# XStream No field found exception

Tags: android, xml-parsing, xstream

Hi I have tried a lot but am not able to find out where am doing wrong in aliasing the tags, my Xml response is this:

```
    <ns1:redcustomerviewResponse SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/weblink">

        <jobcard xsi:type="ns3:Array" ns3:arrayType="ns2:RedCustViewDAO[1]" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">

              <additionalrepair xsi:type="xsd:string">N/A</additionalrepair>
              <custcomplaint xsi:type="xsd:string">SERVICE</custcomplaint>
              <custname xsi:type="xsd:string">BABAN DEOKAR</custname>
              <expdeliverydate xsi:type="xsd:string">17/07/2014</expdeliverydate>
              <hours xsi:type="xsd:string">600</hours>
              <jobCardNo xsi:type="xsd:string">sd</jobCardNo>
              <jobcarddate xsi:type="xsd:string">17/07/2014</jobcarddate>
              <jobcloseddate xsi:type="xsd:string">18/07/2014</jobcloseddate>
              <jobsource xsi:type="xsd:string">Normal-Workshop</jobsource>
              <labourdetails xsi:type="xsd:string">FREE SERVICE</labourdetails>
              <phoneno xsi:type="xsd:string">8270325053</phoneno>
              <serivceadvname xsi:type="xsd:string">SANDEEP</serivceadvname>
              <servDealerCode xsi:type="xsd:string">ABD35926</servDealerCode>
              <servicehstry xsi:type="xsd:string">ServiceHistory</servicehstry>
              <servicesubtype xsi:type="xsd:string">Second</servicesubtype>
              <servicetype xsi:type="xsd:string">Scheduled Services</servicetype>
              <technicianname xsi:type="xsd:string">IRFAN SHAIKH</technicianname>
              <tractorSrNo xsi:type="xsd:string">sd685</tractorSrNo>

        </jobcard>
    </ns1:redcustomerviewResponse>
```

And the Aliasing Class is this

```
    @XStreamAlias("ns1:redcustomerviewResponse")
    public class JobCardResponse {

@XStreamAlias("jobcard")
private Return _return;

public Return getReturn() {
    return _return;
}

public void setReturn(Return _return) {
    this._return = _return;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "AuthenticationResponse [strResponsecdc=" + getReturn().toString() + "]";
}


@XStreamAlias("jobcard")
public static class Return {
    @XStreamAlias("additionalrepair")
    private static String additionalRepair;

    @XStreamAlias("custcomplaint")
    private static String CustComplaint;

    @XStreamAlias("custname")
    private static String customerName;

    @XStreamAlias("expdeliverydate")
    private static String expDeliveryDate;

    @XStreamAlias("hours")
    private static String hours;
    @XStreamAlias("jobCardNo")
    private static String jobCardNo;

    @XStreamAlias("jobcarddate")
    private static String jobcarddate;

    @XStreamAlias("jobsource")
    private static String jobSource;

    @XStreamAlias("jobcloseddate")
    private static String jobCloseDate;

    @XStreamAlias("labourdetails")
    private static String labourDetails;
    @XStreamAlias("phoneno")
    private static String phoneNo;

    @XStreamAlias("serivceadvname")
    private static String serivceAdvName;
    @XStreamAlias("servDealerCode")
    private static String servDealerCode;

    @XStreamAlias("servicehstry")
    private static String serviceHistry;

    @XStreamAlias("servicesubtype")
    private static String serviceSubType;

    @XStreamAlias("servicetype")
    private static String serviceType;
    @XStreamAlias("technicianname")
    private static String technicianName;

    @XStreamAlias("tractorSrNo")
    private static String tractorSrNo;


    public String getCustomerComplaint() {
        return CustComplaint;
    }

    public void setCustomerComplaint(String customerComplaint) {
        this.CustComplaint = customerComplaint;
    }


    public String getAdditionalRepair() {
        return additionalRepair;
    }

    public void setAdditionalRepair(String additionalRepai) {
        this.additionalRepair = additionalRepai;
    }


    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }


    public String getExpDeliveryDate() {
        return expDeliveryDate;
    }

    public void setExpDeliveryDate(String expDeliveryDate) {
        this.expDeliveryDate = expDeliveryDate;
    }

    public String getHours() {
        return hours;
    }

    public void setHours(String hours) {
        this.hours = hours;
    }


    public String getJobCardNo() {
        return jobCardNo;
    }

    public void setJobCardNo(String jobCardNo) {
        this.jobCardNo = jobCardNo;
    }

    public String getLabourDetails() {
        return labourDetails;
    }

    public void setLabourDetails(String labourDetails) {
        this.labourDetails = labourDetails;
    }


    public String getJobcarddate() {
        return jobcarddate;
    }

    public void setJobcarddate(String jobcarddate) {
        this.jobcarddate = jobcarddate;
    }

    public String getJobCloseDate() {
        return jobCloseDate;
    }

    public void setJobCloseDate(String jobCloseDate) {
        this.jobCloseDate = jobCloseDate;
    }


    public String getJobSource() {
        return jobSource;
    }

    public void setJobSource(String jobSourrce) {
        this.jobSource = jobSourrce;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }


    public String getSerivceAdvName() {
        return serivceAdvName;
    }

    public void setSerivceAdvName(String serivceAdvName) {
        this.serivceAdvName = serivceAdvName;
    }

    public String getServDealerCode() {
        return servDealerCode;
    }

    public void setServDealerCode(String servDealerCode) {
        this.servDealerCode = servDealerCode;
    }


    public String getServiceHistry() {
        return serviceHistry;
    }

    public void setServiceHistry(String serviceHistry) {
        this.serviceHistry = serviceHistry;
    }

    public String getServiceSubType() {
        return serviceSubType;
    }

    public void setServiceSubType(String serviceSubType) {
        this.serviceSubType = serviceSubType;
    }

    public String getServiceType() {
        return serviceType;
    }

    public void setServiceType(String serviceType) {
        this.serviceType = serviceType;
    }

    public String getTechnicianName() {
        return technicianName;
    }

    public void setTechnicianName(String technicianName) {
        this.technicianName = technicianName;
    }

    public String getTractorSrNo() {
        return tractorSrNo;
    }

    public void setTractorSrNo(String tractorSrNo) {
        this.tractorSrNo = tractorSrNo;
    }

}
```

}

The above code on execution Shows me this type of error

```
    Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$UnknownFieldException: No such field com.bcone.mahindraGreenClub.response.JobCardResponse$Return.additionalrepair
---- Debugging information ----
field               : additionalrepair
class               : com.bcone.mahindraGreenClub.response.JobCardResponse$Return
required-type       : com.bcone.mahindraGreenClub.response.JobCardResponse$Return
converter-type      : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.ReflectionConverter
path                : /ns1:redcustomerviewResponse/jobcard/additionalrepair
line number         : 8
class[1]            : com.bcone.mahindraGreenClub.response.JobCardResponse
version             : 0.0
```

Am stuck with this from last two 3 days , not able to get out of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `String` fields declared as `static` which means they are bounded to class and are not variable members of your object that can be deserialized:

```
private static String additionalRepair;
```

You should remove `static` from all those fields:

```
private String additionalRepair;
```

Comment: i have removed the static but now it come up with another error that it does not have a no-args constructor..

Comment: Thanku so much , great

Comment: If you have new problem you should ask new question.